# Import Large Unusual File To R

Tags: r, import, large-files

First time poster here, so I'll try and make myself as clear as possible on the help I need. I'm fairly new to R, and this is my first real independent programming experience.

I have stock tick data for about 2.5 years, each day has its own file. The files are .txt and consist of approximately 20-30 million rows, and averaging I guess 360mb each. I am working one file at a time for now. I don't need all the data these files contain, and I was hoping that I could use the programming to minimize my files a bit.

Now my problem is that I am having some difficulties with writing the proper code so R understands what I need it to do.

Let me first show you some of the data so you can get an idea of the formatting.

```
M977
R 64266NRE1VEW107 FI0009653869 2EURXHEL 630 1
R 64516SSA0B 80SHB SE0002798108 8SEKXSTO 40 1
R 645730BBREEW750 FR0010734145 8EURXHEL 640 1
R 64655OXS1C 900SWE SE0002800136 8SEKXSTO 40 1
R 64663OXS1P 450SWE SE0002800219 8SEKXSTO 40 1
R 64801SSIEGV LU0362355355 11EURXCSE 160 1
M978
```

Another snip of data:

```
M732
D 3547742
A 3551497B 200000 67110 02800
D 3550806
D 3547743
A 3551498S 250000 69228 09900
```

So as you can see each line begins with a letter. Each letter denotes what the line means. For instance `R` means order book directory message, `M` means milliseconds after last second, `H` means stock trading action message. There are 14 different letters used in total.

I have used the `readLines` function to import the data into R. This however seems to take a very long time for R to process when I want to work with the data.

Now I would like to write some sort of If function that says if the first letter is `R` then from offset 1 to 4 the code means Market Segment Identifier etc., and have R add columns to these so I can work with the data in a more structured fashion.

What is the best way of importing such data, and also creating some form of structure - i.e. use unique ID information in the line of data to analyze 1 stock at a time for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

f_A <- function(line,tab_A){
  values <- unlist(strsplit(line," "))[2:5]
  rbind(tab_A,list(name_1=as.character(values[1]),name_2=as.numeric(values[2]),name_3=as.numeric(values[3]),name_4=as.numeric(values[4])))
}

tab_A <- data.frame(name_1=character(),name_2=numeric(),name_3=numeric(),name_4=numeric(),stringsAsFactors=F)

for(i in readLines(con="/home/data.txt")){
    switch(strsplit(x=i,split="")[[1]][1],M=cat("1\n"),R=cat("2\n"),D=cat("3\n"),A=(tab_A <- f_A(i,tab_A)))
}
```

And replace `cat()` by different functions that add values to each type of data.frame. Use the pattern of the function `f_A()` to construct others functions and same things for the table structure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have been able to split up the rows, but only for the entire data. I have used the following coding 

`code
starts = c(1,16,30,38,46,50,54) 
ends = c(14,28,35,43,47,50,55) 
ldata = length(data) 
lstarts = length(starts) 
x = substring(data,rep(starts,rep(ldata,lstarts)),rep(ends,rep(ldata,lstarts))) 
matrix(x,ncol=lstarts)`

Is it possible to assign this coding to each initial value? I have tried to write it out after each letter, but that doesn't seem to work. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your `readLines()` command with regular expressions. To get more information about regular expressions, look at the R help site for `grep()`

```
> ?grep
```

So you can go through all the lines, check for each line what it means, and then handle or store the content of the line however you like. (Regular Expressions are also useful to split the data within one line...)